# Run a Javascript function stored in a string variable

Tags: javascript, function

I have got the following function coming from an ajax call which is stored in a string variable.

```
obj.action="DisplayActivity('modalDisplay', 0, 4);"
```

I am trying to run it but without success. I tried with:

```
eval(obj.action);
```

and with:

window[obj.action]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: For that `eval` to work, `DisplayActivity` should be defined somewhere.

Comment: Does `DisplayActivity` actually exist? You may be getting some errors in your console if it doesn't.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lov981gy/  works fine.

Comment: `eval` works, of course only if the function you are trying to call is in scope. `window[obj.action]` makes no sense.

Comment: yes, for sure. the function is already defined. I can run it just calling like that DisplayActivity('modalDisplay', 0, 4); in the same code section. but i need to invoke it from the variable cos it is coming from the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [New Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

```js
let s = "console.log('Hello '+a)",
call = new Function('a', s)

call('world!')
```

Make sure to avoid to call stuffs from a GET/POST or this will lead to be a [typical xss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), allowing to change your DOM from a special crafted link.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's a scoping problem.

Try:

```
eval("global.tmp = function(DisplayActivity){" + obj.action + "};");
global.tmp(DisplayActivity);
```